# Show that h is harmonic iff $\frac{\partial h}{\partial \overline z}$ is conjugate harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I want to solve the following:

Show that h is harmonic iff $\frac{\partial h}{\partial \overline z}$ is conjugate harmonic

My attempt:

$h$ is harmonic iff $\frac{\partial^{2} h}{\partial z \partial{ \overline{z}}}=0$ iff $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\frac{\partial h}{\partial \overline z})=0$

and given that

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}= \frac{\overline {\partial{\overline h}}}{{\partial \overline z}}$$

then $\overline {\frac{\partial h}{\partial \overline z}}$ is analytic iff $\frac{\partial h}{\partial \overline z}$  is conjugate analytic.

Can you tell if I am right ? and If not can you help me to fix the proof? thanks a lot :)

**this is what I don't know if it is true:**

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}= \frac{\overline {\partial{\overline h}}}{{\partial \overline z}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$2\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial h}{\partial y},$$

and so

$$2\frac{\partial \bar{h}}{\partial \bar{z}} = \frac{\partial \bar{h}}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial \bar{h}}{\partial y} = \overline{\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}} = 2\overline{\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}}.$$

Dividing by $2$ and conjugating results in

$$\overline{\frac{\partial \bar{h}}{\partial \bar{z}}} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial z}.$$

Comment: thanks a lot ;) then my proof is complete an correct?

Comment: o no that has to be the conjugate analytic of other function :)

Comment: the title is explicitly the exercise :)

Comment: well if $v$ is a conjugate analytic of $u$ then $u+iv$ is analytic

Comment: but in a previous exercise i have proved that h is harmonic iff $\frac{\partial h}{\partial z }$ is analytic.

Comment: What you wrote in the previous comment -- that's what it means to be a harmonic conjugate, not conjugate analytic.

Comment: right :), but then what means to be conjugate analytic?

Comment: It means that its conjugate is analytic. In the case of exercise, since $h$ is harmonic, $\bar{h}$ is harmonic. So $\frac{\partial \bar{h}}{\partial z}$ is analytic. Since $$\overline{\frac{\partial h}{\partial \bar{z}}} = \frac{\partial \bar{h}}{\partial z},$$ it follows that $\frac{\partial h}{\partial \bar{z}}$ is conjugate analytic.

Comment: then I am right in my proof ?

Comment: there are some typos in your above comment right?

Comment: No, I haven't made any typos.

Comment: well, it should be: $\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}= \overline {\frac{\partial \overline h}{\partial \overline z }}$ rght?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there are typos, but the identity you wanted to prove (and I proved in my answer) and the identity I used in the comment are both valid. Anyway, your work above is correct, although for a proof it should be written more formally.

Comment: ok :) , but then My proof is corrrect, only I have to separate it in both sides of the iff right?

Comment: Yes, you should do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I thought there were  problems with my above proof :), only writting better and that all :) uff thanks a lot

Comment: yes, thats right :)

Comment: Hello again :) @kobe I have thought in anothe proof for this exercise, Can I you tell me if I am right? thanks a lot :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21991/discussion-between-kobe-and-user162343).