# What precisely does the notation $\frac {\partial h} {\partial z}$ mean in this context?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

I am given the following problem.

> Let $Ω\subset \mathbb{C} $ and let $h \in C^1(Ω)$ be such that $\frac {\partial h} {\partial z}=0$. Show that $h(z)=\overline {f(z)}$ for some $f$ analytic in $Ω$.

The $\frac {\partial h} {\partial z}$ notation is mysterious to me. But, after looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191559/show-that-h-is-harmonic-iff-frac-partial-h-partial-overline-z-is-conjuga), I have a guess as to what it means.

Write $h(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y).$ Then $\frac {\partial h} {\partial z}=\frac {[u_x+iv_x]-i[u_y+iv_y]} 2=\frac {u_x+v_y+iv_x-iu_y} 2$. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: It's just the ordinary derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$.

Comment: @anomaly you can write that as an answer. It doesn't need to contain anything more